# How to test if a capture is defined in Perl regexp matching?

Tags: perl

How to test if a capture is defined in Perl regexp matching?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.10;
my $str="foobar
barfoo";

while($str =~ m/(?:(f.*))|(?:(b.*))/g) {
    say "+ $1";
    say "- $2";
}
```

It outputs

```
+ foobar
- 
+ 
- barfoo
```

while what I want is

```
+ foobar
- barfoo
```

I.e. if `$1` or `$2` aren't matched, it shouldn't print.

Comment: `$1`, `$2`, etc aren't backreferences. "Backreference" refers to `\1`, `\2`, etc. They are regex patterns that match strings captured earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is you aren't testing if it's defined, so it's going to print the +/- either way.

```
while($str =~ m/(?:(f.*))|(?:(b.*))/g) {
    say "+ $1" if defined($1);
    say "- $2" if defined($2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `defined(...)` function. If `$1` isn't defined then `defined($1)` will return false.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to not rely on the side effects of setting `$1` and friends. It is a cause of a family of bugs, as you demonstrated, and should be avoided. Instead, simply use the return values from the match operator.

```
while(my ($plus, $minus) = $str =~ m/(?:(f.*))|(?:(b.*))/g) {
    say "+ $plus";
    say "- $minus";
```

Comment: +1, that sounds like sound advice to me. Especially because for failed matches, $2 and such may refer to the results of previous succeeding matches. Assuming TIMTOWTDI, there's got to be a different, hopefully more explicit way of detecting whether a match matched, but I can't seem to find one.

Comment: Which part do you want to be more explicit? If the return value of the match operation is false, it didn't match. I write `if (SOMEMATCH) {` or `while (SOMEMATCH) {` all the time to guard against the failure case. Hundreds of other functions in Perl, both built-in and 3rd party, behave alike (i.e. returning a false value on failure).

Comment: The syntax. Of course, it is routine to use the return value of a function. But SOMEMATCH is an infix expression, and looks like an assignment, too (yeah, it isn't, but that "=" irks me). I tend to avoid using the value of such expressions, because I consider that hard to read and review. By "more explicit" I mean something like `$matched= $regex->match($input)`, such as Regexp::Common provides (found that just now).